# Angular interface adding subitems how to

Tags: angular, angular12

I want to categorise the interface items in my dashboard so I’m trying something like this:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    title?: string;
    dashboard: any[
        { 
        id: number; 
        label: string; 
        key: any
        // etc…
    };
    ] 
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would suggest. Its more redable in the sense that it specifies "an array of type"

```
export interface Dashboard{
  id: number;
  label: string;  
  key: any;
}
export interface MyInterface {
  title?: string;
  dashboard: Dashboard[];
}
```

Comment: And how do I use it? for example: dashboard.id: 1  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
dashboard: { 
    id: number; 
    label: string; 
    key: any
    // etc…
}[];
```

you put the type of what's in the array before the array notation, denoting that it is an array of this type, rather an array of `any` which is what `any[]` means.

Comment: I get this when I try to use / initialize it ... Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ id: number; label: string; key: string; }'.  ... I'm trying this...  init: MyInterface = {
    Title: ‘some ‘title,
    dashboard: { 
      id: 1,
      label: 'string'; 
      key: 'any'
  }[];
  };

Comment: I can't read code in comments.